# Magento - Zero order in One Step checout

Tags: magento, customization

In Magento we installed a paid extension - [One Step check out](http://www.onestepcheckout.com/)

It was worked fine, some other developer customized the code for Free Shipping for particular location.

After the customization the order is placed for 0 value. i.e the product has value, but the sub total, shipping and tax value set 0, please refer attached sceenshot.
[image]

I don't know where the issue is, please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Based on the screenshot it seems all ordered items are canceled. This can be a reason for zero subtotal.

Comment: If you have a versioning system, I would recommend doing a review of all changes which have been made to that extension.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @PéterGulyás : Once we received the 0 order value then we cancelled the order. Even though the order is cancelled the subtotal wont be 0.

I will go through the extension again.